# Standard reference for thermodynamic properties for octane

Tags: thermodynamics

where can I find thermodynamics properties for octane at saturated Temp.$T_s$?
I need this properties or where can i find all ?

$$liquid-density=\rho_l=?$$
$$vapor-density=\rho_v=?$$ 
$$latent-heat-of-evaporation=h_fg=?$$
$$liquid-kinematic-viscosity=\mu_l=? $$
$$liquid-conductivity=k_l=?$$

Comment: When you ask for something like that, please always define all you symbols. For one thing, the symbols are not universal and furthermore, you can't search for a symbol.

Comment: sorry I edited it ...

Comment: Have you checked the NIST database, as well as a standard MSDS for Octane?

Comment: how can i check it ?

Comment: Check the infobox on the wikipedia page. If this is not "standard" enough for your purposes, why not check the [sources](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Chemical_infobox#References) of the infobox itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [NIST Chemistry Webbook](http://webbook.nist.gov) maintained by the National Institute of Standards and Technology is a freely searchable database of chemical and physical data on a vast array of substances.

Everything you want for octane can be found there.